# GridView Stretch Row Height?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using GridView in my application. And i am wondering if there is an equivalent to **GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH** , for row heights.

In other words, i want the height of the images in the GridView cells, to be stretched, like their width is.

Is there an easy way? Or I would have to fix it through the image adapter ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image view whose width changes according to height. This way if the `GridView` only has an `ImageView`, it will stay squared.

For example:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, w, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```

Comment: that would be good for short displays. but in most of them the height of the GridView is always greater than the width.